# File upload insert into database

Tags: php, file, session, upload

I am struggling to come up with a process to upload a file with a form i am working on an application that needs the user to upload a file then insert it into a database.

i have setup a database with.

```
   TABLE - tracks
    track_name
    track_bpm
    track_rate
    track_ref
    track_special
    track_file // This is where i need the uploaded file to go
```

I am stuck on process here is where i have got so far.
http://html5up.users35.interdns.co.uk/

I am looking at doing a you tube style filling out the form while your file uploads, the file could be up to 2gig, then insert file when completed into sessions id here is a snippet of my file-upload.php

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tracks SET track_file = '".$file_name."'
WHERE session_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");
```

Can someone please help me with the correct process or at least a decent tutorial or way off doing this correctly been Googling for ages.

Is passing a session id the correct way to do this?

Any help please everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advices:

1. mysql_* functions will be deprecated soon, use PDO or mysqli
2. <strike>Don't store files in the database, try to store only paths to the files.</strike>
3. Learn, how to sanitize SQL-queries.

Comment: Hi oz i am only storing the file name in the database the files are stored on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your files into the database (See [Why store binary data in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778380/why-store-binary-data-in-mysql)), in MySQL that's done in a [BLOB field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html).

You insert the data into the table by reading it from the uploaded file and then send that data over to the database with a standard SQL query.

There are plenty of tutorials available on the web, one is [Uploading Files To MySQL Database](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx).

If you store the file on disk, then just store the file on disk. Just take care that the insertion/updating/deleting of the data in the database is atomic with the operation on the file (creation of the file/updating;renaming/deletion).

Comment: hi hakre thanks for the response its more the process i am after i found tonnes of file upload tutorials like this also but now off them implement a upload progress bar drag and drop or anything with a nice ui, and no info on upload progress unless you are using chrome. do you know of any example with a nice uploader??? thanks